# Dart : Printing integer along with string

Tags: dart, concatenation, string-concatenation

Consider the below code.

```
void main() {
  int num = 5;
  print('The number is ' + num);
}
```

When I try to print the value for the variable num, I get the exception : `The argument type 'int' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'`.

How do I go about in printing num?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In order to print the value of the int along with the String you need to use string interpolation:

```
void main() {
  int num = 5;
  print("The number is $num");
}
```

Comment: This approach also worked for me in a RichText wdiget. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Just add [toString()](https://api.dartlang.org/dev/2.0.0-dev.63.0/dart-core/Object/toString.html) to your int. Similar to JS.

```
void main() {
  int num = 5;
  print('The number is ' + num.toString()); // The number is 5
}
```

Comment: This is not allowed, throughs a error in VSCode. Use method given by Pawel L.

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
int age = 10;
double location = 21.424567;
bool gender = true;
String name = "The EasyLearn Academy";

print(age); 
print(location);
print(gender); 
print(name); 

print("age $age"); 
print("location $location");
print("gender $gender"); 
print("name $name}"); 

print("age " + age.toString()); 
print("location " + location.toString());
print("gender " + gender.toString()); 
print("name " + name);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Could use ${} in order to concatenate with return of function:

```
print('$key|${favoriteBooksBox.get(key)}');
```